# " apache2.service is not active, cannot reload "

Tags: server, 16.04

When running `sudo service apache2 reload`, I get the error:

```
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload
```

**Output of `sudo service apache2 status`**

```
root@gamma:~# sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2016-10-15 08:23:11 UTC; 2h 28min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 2203 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited,     status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 2185 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 15 08:23:10 gamma systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Oct 15 08:23:10 gamma apache2[2185]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Oct 15 08:23:11 gamma apache2[2185]: Action 'start' failed.
Oct 15 08:23:11 gamma apache2[2185]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 15 08:23:11 gamma apache2[2185]:  *
Oct 15 08:23:11 gamma apache2[2203]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Oct 15 08:23:11 gamma apache2[2203]:  *
Oct 15 08:23:11 gamma systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
root@gamma:~# sudo service apache2 reload
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
root@gamma:~#
```

**Output of** `error.log`

```
root@gamma:/# sudo service apache2 force-reload
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
root@gamma:/# grep '15 08:23:' /var/log/apache2/error.log
root@gamma:/# zgrep -h 'Oct 15 08:23:' /var/log/apache2/error.log*
[Sat Oct 15 08:23:11.012917 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2202] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate   bot.testingsite.cf:443:0 (with chain), check /etc/apache2/ssl/bot.testingsite.cf.crt
[Sat Oct 15 08:23:11.013037 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2202] SSL Library Error:    error:0906D06C:PEM rou  tines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format -   or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Sat Oct 15 08:23:11.013056 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2202] SSL Library Error: error:140DC009:SSL rou  tines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
root@gamma:/#
```

I tried to enable ssl certificate. Namecheap provided me a file & I used it on ..cf.crt file. 
After seeing this error I tried to validate via DCV method. But Still I get this error. `sudo service apache2 restart` does not give any output.

Comment: Can we see the output of sudo service apache2 status?

Comment: @ManuelAlvarez Post edited

Comment: Can you also add the output of `grep '15 08:23:' /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: If there is no output, run `zgrep -h 'Oct 15 08:23:' /var/log/apache2/error.log*` instead.

Comment: I also tried to reboot entire OS , but it did not help.

Comment: **conf file** 

`<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName bot.testingsite.cf
        ServerAdmin mrsiddiki@gmail.com

        SSLEngine on

        DocumentRoot /var/www/bot.testingsite.cf/public_html/chatBot/public
        <Directory "/var/www/bot.testingsite.cf/public_html/chatBot/public/">
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost> `

Comment: reviewers: OP stated in a comment that he "had to reinstall the OS".

Answer (score 22):

Do

```
apachectl stop
```

It will throw an error message regarding syntax error in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file

Correct it.

Then do

```
apachectl stop
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Now reloading of apache2 will work

Do

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Comment: Actually, that was month ago and i had to reinstall OS . By the Way, Thank you for the answer.

Comment: This worked for me!